# Gmail smtp Hostname does not match the server certificate

Tags: ssl, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having an error with `gmail` gem while trying to send a mail, this is working fine on local, and was working fine on heroku, but now im moving this app to a VPS server. This is the error:

```
e = g.compose do
   to 'test@gmail.com'
   subject 'testasea'
   body 'test'
end

=> #<Mail::Message:25450040, Multipart: false, Headers: <From: .......>
e.deliver!
=> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: hostname does not match the server certificate
```

I've added this into an initializer file, without any luck:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :openssl_verify_mode  => 'none' # I've tested with 0 and false,
```

}

I tried to monkey path the class

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLSocket.class_eval do
 def post_connection_check(hostname)
   return true
 end
end
```

with no luck, when I do that i receive a `535 Incorrect authentication data`, however I know data is ok because i can do

```
g.inbox.count :read
```

And it returns me the right number.

I would like to know:

- the incorrect certificate is the one my server (smtp client) is sending? or the one that is received by gmail smtp server?
- why it works in local?
- Why if i monkey path the class I received an authentication error?
- Is there any workaround? i dont care if is not safe, is just a tenting application,.

Comment: I also tried to use mail gem directly and got exactly the same behaviour and errors.

Comment: This might be a transient error - it appears gmail has swapped out their SSL certificates *again* today.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a guess, but if you are in a `WHM VPS` there is a function that restricts outgoing SMTP connections, you can find it in Tweak Settings.

```
 Restrict outgoing SMTP to root, exim, and mailman (FKA SMTP Tweak)
```

It redirects all SMTP connections, If this is enabled you will receive your server self-signed ssl certificate, and if you bypass it using the monkey patch or setting configuration to dont check ssl certificate you will probably found an authentication error as you are in fact connecting to the LOCAL SMTP server.

Just disable it and test again.